# PHP - how does serialize work? I need to serialize an array manually

Tags: php, serialization

I'm using CSV Import Suite for WooCommerce. One of the columns has to be a serialized array.

I'm trying to find out, how the serialize function in PHP works, as I need to recreate that in Excel. I have a simple array:

```
array(0 => 'text', 2 => 'some other text')
```

which gives me:

```
a:2:{i:0;s:4:"text";i:2;s:15:"some other text";}
```

What's the logic of how the serialized string is built?

Comment: There's probably a better solution here. Why do you need to recreate it in Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To break down your example:

`a:2:{i:0;s:4:"text";i:2;s:15:"some other text";}`

- **a**rray with 2 items
- key is an **i**nteger: 0, with a **s**tring value of length 4, containing 'text'.
- key is an **i**nteger: 2, with a **s**tring value of length 15, containing 'some other text'

Whether you should actually attempt this is another thing though. There's probably a better solution to the root problem.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this is something like `a:2` where `a` stands for `array`, `2` is element count. Then you got `i` (integer), its value, `;` as separator. then another element, `s` (string), its length and the value.